# I'm trying to use the Roblox api to change a group status but I keep on getting a 401 error

Tags: python, roblox

```
import requests

payload = {"message": "string"}
payloaddata = {'username': "XXX", 'password': "XXX"}

r = requests.patch('https://groups.roblox.com/v1/groups/XXX/status', json=payload, data=payloaddata)
print(r.text)
print(r)
```

Kind of new to coding so I would appreciate it if you could help

Comment: Take a look at https://httpstatuses.com/401, your request likely needs an authentication token as a header.

Comment: @Kylaaa Could you maybe show me an example?

Comment: I don't know enough about Python to give a decent example. But instead of putting the username and password in the payload, try hitting the login url with the username and password, then use the resulting cookies and headers in your group status request.